# How to create a Pandas DataFrame from a list of variable length

Tags: python, pandas, list

I would like to create a single row `pandas-DataFrame`  from a list of variable length:

`data = [x1, x2, x3, ...]`  where `xi`s are integers.

I have tried with `df=pd.DataFrame(data)`, but I get a dataframe with a single column and multiple rows, instead of one row and multiple columns.

Comment: `df=pd.DataFrame(data).T`

Comment: or `df=pd.DataFrame([data])`.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the name of the column you would like these integers to be in.

```py
import pandas

# Your data
x1 = 1
x2 = 2
x3 = 3
data = [x1, x2, x3]

df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=["some_column_name"])
```

Output:

```py
   some_column_name
0                 1
1                 2
2                 3
```